# How to renew expired LinkedIn access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to renew my expired access token like the documentation:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

I'm trying to make GET requests like this:

First GET (used to get code):

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=XXX&scope=r_fullprofile&state=hyriedsdsv56uvenn5eouvnjedfgdfgio5&redirect_uri=http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com
```

The return of this request is something like this:

```
http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com/?code=MY_CODE&state=hyriedsdsv56uvenn5eouvnjedfgdfgio5
```

After this, I have to make the final request to get my access token:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=XXX&redirect_uri=http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX
```

And LinkedIn is returning this error message:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more then once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired"}
```

Does anyone know what should I do to fix this? My authorization token can`t be expired because I'm using at the time that I get one.

I am using the correct key and app secret.

Thank you! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20 second seems expiration time between the two. Your domain.com/.. should immediately make a accessToken call and store it in client DB.

Comment: Thanks @Optional... that was the problem =)